# How to add a line inside an equation

Tags: equations, text

I would like to introduce a line break in text line inside an equation.

What I have done is:

```
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\text{Reactividad\ relativa \\ Hidr\'ogeno\ secundario}}{\text{Reactividad\ relativa\\ Hidr\'ogeno\ secundario}}&=d
\end{align*}
```

And what I would like to reproduce is the left side of the equal:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use variables and explain them  in proper sentences? What I see in the picture makes me cringe.

Comment: I have a big lack of latex language and for this reason I cannot give you a proper answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variant, with the `\Centerstack` command,, which automatically starts text mode, and can take an optional argument to set the alignment of the lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation} %% \Longstack is probably better, look at the manual for stackengine...
        \frac{\,\Centerstack[l]{Relative reactivity of \\ a secondary hydrogen}\,}%
        {\Centerstack[l]{Relative reactivity of \\ a primary hydrogen}}
        = \frac{\,\Centerstack[l]{yield of product from \\ secondary hydrogen abstraction}\Bigm / \Centerstack[l]{number of \\ secondary hydrogens}\,}%
     {\Centerstack[l]{yield of product from \\ primary hydrogen abstraction}\Bigm /\Centerstack[l]{number of \\ primary hydrogens}}%
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Define a suitable command for those “textual variables”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tvar}[1]{%
  \textup{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    #1
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\tvar{Reactividad relativa \\ Hidr\'ogeno secundario}}
     {\tvar{Reactividad relativa\\ Hidr\'ogeno primario}}
=
\frac{
      \left(\tvar{Abc def \\ ghi klm}\right)\bigg/
      \left(\tvar{Abc def \\ ghi klm}\right)
     }
     {
      \left(\tvar{Abc def \\ ghi klm}\right)\bigg/
      \left(\tvar{Abc def \\ ghi klm}\right)
     }
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You **can** do it, which does not mean you *should* do it. I agree with @Johannes_B, using proper variables will increase the readability a lot.

You can use [`stackengine`](https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine?lang=en) for these things:

[image]

and still, this is IMHO better:

[image]

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation} %% \Longstack is probably better, look at the manual for stackengine... 
        \frac{\text{\stackunder{Relative reactivity of}{a secondary hydrogen}}}%
        {\text{\stackunder{Relative reactivity of}{a primary hydrogen}}} \cdots
    \end{equation}

    \bigskip

    But this is better: 

    Call $R_2$ the relative reactivity of a secondary hydrogen, $R_1$ the relative reactivity of a primary hydrogen, \dots
    \begin{equation}
        \frac{R_2}{R_1}\cdots
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```